# In java, if a method NOT inherited by any subclass is called, whether dynamic binding or static binding is used?

Tags: java, inheritance, dynamic-binding, static-binding

In java, if a method NOT inherited by any subclass is called, whether dynamic binding or static binding is used?

I know it won't make any difference to the output in this particular case, but just wanted know this.

Comment: Do you mean if it's not overridden?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe that method calls in Java always use dynamic binding. Static methods and access to private members use static binding.

Comment: @pcalcao - yeah, I too believe what you said to be true, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance method calls in Java always use dynamic binding. Static methods and direct access to private members use static binding.

In length:
http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html

This article explains it pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the class or method is marked `final`, it could be overridden by new types introduced at runtime by a class loader.  In this sense they are still 'dynamic'.

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, JVM knows all classes loaded, and whether a method is overridden; the `final` modifier on methods doesn't matter to JVM.

With that knowledge, JVM will optimize calls to methods that are not overridden; the binding is "static" in that sense.